# is there a convenient equivalent of "find -mtime <days>" for parts of a day

Tags: bash, find

Suppose you want to find files modified in the last 5 minutes, using the `find` command.

The `-mtime` option, which can be used to specify a number of days, is documented as discarding any fractional part.

> File was last modified n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out how
>   many 24-hour periods ago the file was last modified, any fractional
>   part is ignored.

*(Actually it's in the man page under `-atime`, where it has an analogous meaning. I've replaced "accessed" with "modified" here.)*

In a script, it would be possible to do:

```
find $starting_dir -newermt "$(date -d '5 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
```

but this form is a bit unwieldy for convenient interactive use.

Is there a more concise formulation that can be conveniently remembered and typed when needed?

Assume that the GNU versions of common command-line tools are installed, but not any local customisations such as command aliases or helper scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU find has -mmin primary for that. For example,

```
find -mmin -6
```

prints files that have been modified in the last five minutes.

Comment: So simple. Somehow I'd missed that...